Dynamic routing using Nginx to newly created endpoints
I shall brief my usecase first followed up with the question. i have a python flask application that is supposed to be the entrypoint, and once they signup, the python backend strips the username from the email and spins up a docker containter on the host machine. Once the container is spun , a url is displayed on the flask application and there is a vhost.d that holds the routing changes required to forward traffic to these newly created containers based on the /paths. So lets say user-a comes and hits the python app and provides the mail as user-a@email.com and this would spin up a docker contianer with the network alias a user-a. There's a proxy pass directive added to the vhost.d file to route all requests in the path /user-a to http://user-a:port. So ideally I'd want the same workflow to be made for how many ever users are going to signup from the python app. Is there any other way of routing addressing this usecase, or am I in the wrong place of using path based routing instead of host based routing.
I tried this with both nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy and jwilder/nginx-proxy. i was able to find some success with jwilder/nginx-proxy. On the docker compose file I have provided VIRTUAL_HOST=hostname.app for both the python application and for every newly created vnc docker containers. My expectation was, the python app should be routed to /frontend path and all the other vnc containers should be routed through /username path. But since these both are using the same VIRTUAL_HOST, this created a loadbalancing configuration between the two containers, therefore everytime I reload I get a different response.

How would you address this use case without Docker?  (Try simulating it using the subprocess module to launch python -m http.server.)  How will this scale to hundreds of users?  The Docker socket can be used to trivially take over the entire host system; how will your application protect against this?

With docker its fairly straightforward. Look at it like spawning a user specific tunnel session. Yes, to spin up containers, I'd need the application to interact with the host docker socket. Why is that seen as a problem.

You can docker run -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/passwd or similar and trivially take over the host.  You also need to keep track of the containers you've launched, even if your process has exited.  If you want to run this in a different container environment like Kubernetes, the Docker socket won't work.
